# Estoy intentando de hacer uso FirebaseStorage en Angular Versión 11

Tags: angular, firebase

Estoy intentando hacer uso de FireStorage en mi proyecto de Angular en la versión
**Angular CLI: 11.2.6** pero al momento de obtener la url de la imagen subida con el método de **task.getChanges()** me arroja un error

> Type 'Observable<number | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.

> Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.

> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'

> uploadPercent: Observable;

> urlImage: Observable;

ya importe la clase Observable  **import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';** en mi componente que estoy usando. Estoy revisando la documentación oficial de Angular que aparece en el gitHub [GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angularfire), revise toda documentación sigo los pasos que dicen pero no me quiere funcionar, lo que tengo  en mi componente es lo siguiente.

```javascript
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { UploadScriptsService } from 'src/app/services/upload-scripts.service';
    import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
    /*importo el servicio conectionService para mandar datos*/
    import { ConectionService } from 'src/app/services/conection.service';
    /*importo el Storage de firebase */
    import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-add-card',
      templateUrl: './add-card.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./add-card.component.css']
    })
    export class AddCardComponent implements OnInit {
      /*En el constructor se crea la varible para poder usar el servicio de conectionService*/
      /*En el constructor se crea la varible para poder usar el servicio de FireStorage*/
      constructor(private conection: ConectionService, private storage: AngularFireStorage) {

      }

      private script: UploadScriptsService = new UploadScriptsService;

      /*Variables con las cuales envio los datos para cargar a firebase*/
      item: any = {
        title: '',
        text: '',
        image: ''
      };

      uploadPercent: Observable<number>;
      urlImage: Observable<string>;
      
      imageSrc: string = "";
      userFile: any;
      imageSelected: any;



      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.script.cargaScripts(["uploadCard"])
      }

      //inicializar el arreglo
      funcionOne() {
        /* this.script.cargaScripts(["prueba"]) */
      }

      addCard() {
        this.conection.addCard(this.item);
        this.item.title = '';
        this.item.text = '';
        this.item.image = '';
        /* 
            this.uploadBtn?.addEventListener("clcik",function(){
        
            }*/
      }

      onUpload(e: any) {
        /* console.log("subir", e.target.files[0]); */

        const id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        const filePath = `imagesCards/${id}`;
        const refe = this.storage.ref(filePath);
        const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);
        this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();
      

      }

    }
```

Comment: Puedes revisar que error esta dando en la consola, y en la consola del navegador. Segun lo que he revisado no tienes ningun error. Aveces ese tipo de erroes es por el tipado extricto que puedes tener en los archivos `TypeScript .ts`.

Comment: @DavElsanto el error que arroja es el siguiente

`Error: src/app/components/add-card/add-card.component.ts:33:3 - error TS2564: Property 'urlImage' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

33   urlImage :Observable<number>;
     ~~~~~~~~`

Comment: El error es porque no inicializas las variable de tipo observable solo la declaras. Debes inicializarlas con new observable. Revisa la documentación de observables.

Comment: Además tu servicio debe estar en el constructor para la correcta inyección

Comment: @DavElsanto ya logré obtener  la solución  y tenia que poner **urlImage: Observable<string | undefined>;** antes del constructor y dentro del constructor poner **this.urlImage = new Observable;**

Me ayudaste bastante, gracias amigo.